# undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass in Ruby Tokbox API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to use the tokbox api and have the following error:

```
Started GET "/en/stream" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-02 18:38:57 +0800
Processing by UsersController#stream as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  Rendering users/stream.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/stream.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <%= javascript_include_tag "//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/TB.min.js" %>
    2: <h1>Your stream</h1>
    3: <div id="publisher"></div>
    4: Link to your stream: <%= link_to watch_url(@stream.user.id), watch_url(@stream.user.id) %>

app/views/users/stream.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_users_stream_html_erb__3447765015494674598_70186549432640'
```

My User/stream.html.erb looks like:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/TB.min.js" %>
    <h1>Your stream</h1>
    <div id="publisher"></div>
    Link to your stream: <%= link_to watch_url(@stream.user.id), watch_url(@stream.user.id) %>
```

My UserController looks like :

```
def stream
    @stream = User.find(params[:id]).stream
    @stream     = current_user.stream || current_user.create_stream
    gon.opentok = opentok_data(@stream)
  end

  def watch
    @stream = User.find(params[:id]).stream
    gon.opentok = opentok_data(@stream)
  end

  private

  def opentok_data(stream)
    token = OpenTokClient.generate_token(stream.opentok_session_id)
    { sessionId: stream.opentok_session_id, apiKey: Figaro.env.opentok_api_key, token: token }
  end
```

My user model has one stream, and my stream model has one user.
Does anyone knows why it is not recognising the user ?

Comment: What line is throwing the error can you tell from the logs?

Comment: It is this one ` Link to your stream: <%= link_to watch_url(@stream.user.id), watch_url(@stream.user.id) %>`

returning : `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass)`

Comment: Somehow your `@stream` is nil. And you are assigning the value to `@stream` twice. Check out line 2 and 3. You need to check that also. Paste the dump of `params` from your server logs as well to the question.

Comment: Hi kartikey, how do i get the dump of params from the server pls ?

Comment: Reproduce the error you are getting. Go to your terminal/command-line where you started `rails s`.  Copy the logs of the last request and paste it here.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the error with all what i can see in the console in my original post

Comment: Do you have authentication(login) functionality in the app? How do you get `current_user` do you know?

Comment: I have authentification via Devise

Comment: this line `@stream = User.find(params[:id]).stream` is redundant. replace it with `@stream     = current_user.stream || current_user.create_stream` and stop trying to find out who user is redundantly , you already have `current_user`

Comment: Okay. Are you sure you are getting the current logged in user in `current_user`. Have you used `before_action :authenticate_user!` in your `application_controller.rb`?

Comment: @KartikeyTanna it would have thrown another error much earlier if that was the case

Comment: @seethrough, ok, that was removed. thank you.

Comment: @KartikeyTanna, yes 100% i logged in multiple times just in case.

Comment: install `gem 'byebug'` and then try to sneak into this, just type `byebug` in your controller somewhere in the `stream` method and investigate, would `current_user.stream` return true or not and would it return what you want. i mean after inserting byebug keyword into the controller your dev server will stop execution and wait for your input, head to server console and just like in irb try to some values

Comment: I tried at the top of `stream`  and at the bottom, it does help seeing anything. The terminal doesn t flip to byebug mode

Comment: Hi @user9680695, did you find the solution at the end ? I am facing the same issue. I looked at the github (https://blog.sumatosoft.com/build-your-live-streaming-service-with-ruby-on-rails-and-tokbox/#comment-8713)  multiple time but do not see what i am missing. I suspect the example is missing some elements.